# Github Search: how to search in multiple languages

Tags: search, github

[Github search supports](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/):

```
<keyword> language:javascript
```

But I want something like:

```
<keyword> language:javascript OR language:typescript
```

So that I can sort them by stars or do other filters in a single search.

The reason is: with `typescript` becoming more and more popular each day, a single filter with `language:javascript` is no longer enough.

Comment: You could do a non-specific search. GitHub lists all the files and on the right you can choose which languages you want to see. Among the list will be JavaScript and typescript. You can toggle between them.

Comment: This is one workaround, but I also want to sort them by stars in a single search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2020, you can now search multiple languages:

```
<keyword> language:javascript language:typescript
```

This will search for any Javascript or Typescript repo matching the keyword.

(I would expect nested `OR` to work, but the addition of parentheses for grouping leads to unexpected result counts.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the command line by using github Api by a + symbol:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositoriesq=$guitar-scales+language:"javascript"+language:"typescript"&per_page=100&page=$i" | jq ".items[] | {name, language}"
```

And here is a sample from the search result:

```
{
  "name": "react-boilerplate",
  "language": "JavaScript"
}
{
  "name": "electrode",
  "language": "JavaScript"
}
{
  "name": "claygl",
  "language": "JavaScript"
}
{
  "name": "mean",
  "language": "TypeScript"
}
{
  "name": "rapidpro",
  "language": "JavaScript"
}
{
  "name": "react-native-scaling-drawer",
  "language": "JavaScript"
}
```