# Search for GitHub repos written in given proportion of languages

Tags: github, search

GitHub search [`language:` qualifier](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#language-qualifier) allows [searching for repos written in multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77071971/1429450), but is there a way to search for repos that are, e.g., 25% JavaScript and 75% HTML? Or 70% Pug, 20% JavaScript, and 10% SCSS?